# OperationalError, connecting to another Django/DB project

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to connect to another database (project-B) that also uses Django. I would like to ask for help on how to resolve the following error?

Here's the error from Django debug:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running
>   on host "111.222.333.444" and accepting   TCP/IP connections on port
>   5432?

Here's the firewall from project-B

> Status: active Logging: on (low) Default: deny (incoming), allow
>   (outgoing), disabled (routed) New profiles: skip
>
> > To                         Action      From 5432
> >     ALLOW IN    111.222.333.444

I also put it in the allowed host

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '111.222.333.444']

Other than that, I have not modified anything from project-B.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall allows requests from `111.222.333.444`, which is effectively blocking all hosts other than same host connection.